# Applied tween inside each(), how do I use reverse()?

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs, tween

Let's suppose I apply a tween to each element on my canvas

```
elements.each(function (element) {
    new Kinetic.Tween({
        node: element,
        rotationDeg: 180
    }).play();
});
```

All items have been tweened and have passed from their original state to a final state. My question is: How would I apply a reverse() to revert each item to their original state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the tweens inside an array, and then loop through that array and use `.reverse()`

```
    elements = stage.get('Rect');
    var tweenArray = [];

    // reverse tween
    document.getElementById('reverse').addEventListener('click', function () {
        for (var i=0; i<tweenArray.length; i++) {
            tweenArray[i].reverse();
        }
    }, false);

    // play tween forward
    document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', function () {
        elements.each(function (element) {
            var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
                node: element,
                rotationDeg: 180
            }).play();
            tweenArray.push(tween);
        });
    }, false);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/QmCsk/)

Comment: +1 Yep, nice illustration!  I know it's just an illustration, but in production be sure to prevent consecutive clicks of either play or reverse.  For example, clicking play twice messes up the animation.

Comment: Thanks @markE and you are absolutely correct, so thanks for pointing that out :D