# How to disable and enable click on KinectJS shape?

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

Suppose I create a tween for each element and push each tween inside an array:

```
var myArray = [];

data.on('click', function () {
    var layer = this.parent.parent;
    var elements = layer.get(".element");

    elements.each(function (element) {
        myTween = new Kinetic.Tween({
            node: elements[0],
            angleDeg: 60,
            easing: Kinetic.Easings.EaseInOut,
            rotationDeg: 180
        }).play();
        myArray.push(myTween );
    });
})
```

Then I loop through my array to apply a **reverse()** when clicking on a button:

```
button.on('click', function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        myArray[i].reverse();
    }
}, false);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to disable the click event right after the tween, so I can apply a reverse(), and only after my reverse is called, enable the element click again.

For some reason, clicking on an element several times breakes the reverse and it does wacky things.

So it would do the following:

1. Click on element
2. Tween element
3. Disable click on element
4. Click on reverse button
5. Reverse element
6. Enable click on element

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.off()` function to unbind events: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-remove-event-listener-with-kineticjs/

And you already know how to use the `.on()` function.

To make things a little easier, put your `.on()` function into a custom function, in this example I'll call it **`bindTweenClick()`**

Once `data` is clicked, use `.off('click')`.

When you click on `button` reverse the tween, and then rebind the events.

```
function bindTweenClick() {
  data.on('click', function () {
    var layer = this.parent.parent;
    var elements = layer.get(".element");

    elements.each(function (element) {
      myTween = new Kinetic.Tween({
        node: elements[0],
        angleDeg: 60,
        easing: Kinetic.Easings.EaseInOut,
        rotationDeg: 180
      }).play();
      myArray.push(myTween );
    });
    this.off('click');
  })
}(); // <-- Self Invoke

button.on('click', function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i].reverse();
  }
  bindTweenClick();
}, false);
```

**Side Note:**

If you are trying to prevent the user from clicking the tween multiple times as suggested by the comment from markE in this your previous thread [Applied tween inside each(), how do I use reverse()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931871/applied-tween-inside-each-how-do-i-use-reverse)

Then instead of unbinding and rebinding the `click` event like you are asking for in this question, I would suggest two options:

1. If you're using a button to call the tween still, deactivate the button until the tween is finished, then activate the button. This is cleaner than unbinding and rebinding.
2. Even better might be: instead of creating a new Tween every time you click "Play", create all the tweens and push it into the array. THEN play all the tweens on click:

   ```
   elements = stage.get('Rect');
   var tweenArray = [];

   elements.each(function (element) {
     var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
       node: element,
       rotationDeg: 180
     });
     tweenArray.push(tween);
   });

   // reverse tween
   document.getElementById('reverse').addEventListener('click', function () {
     for (var i = 0; i < tweenArray.length; i++) {
       tweenArray[i].reverse();
     }
   }, false);

   // play tween forward
   document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', function () {
     for (var i = 0; i < tweenArray.length; i++) {
       tweenArray[i].play();
     }
   }, false);
   ```

   This way, you aren't creating a new Tween on click every time, which updates the position of the node in question, causing the undesired tween effect (and overpopulating the `tweenArray`)

I've updated the original [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/QmCsk/)

Comment: Thanks again projeqht. Promise I'll show you the finished project. You'll like it.

Comment: Looking forward to it! :)